# Using NOT IN with JOIN Statement

Tags: mysql, join

How do I make a NOT IN work with JOIN Statement?
Here's my query below:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM products A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN productmeta B ON A.id=B.product_id 
WHERE(B.group_id IS NULL OR B.group_id=0) 
AND  (B.collection_id IS NULL OR B.collection_id=0)
AND   B.id NOT IN (SELECT collection_id FROM collections)
```

Comment: This query looks syntactically valid => it means it works

Comment: Please explain in better detail what is not happening.. there may be a better way to do it.

Comment: In what way is this not working for you? There needs to be some sample data, a description of what you're trying to do, and sample output that you want that the query doesn't produce. The query is correct as far as syntax goes; it's hard to say why it doesn't produce the results you want without knowing what you want to get from it.

Comment: Better yet post some sample data that represents the problem and a desired outcome

Comment: sorry about that, let me just rephrase my question. How could I write a condition in the last "AND" clause where it only do a "B.id NOT IN (SELECT collection_id FROM collections)" if B.id evaluates to not null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the third clause.  `NULL` is always going to cause it to fail.  But that is easy to test for:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM products A LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     productmeta B 
     ON A.id=B.product_id 
WHERE (B.group_id IS NULL OR B.group_id=0) AND
      (B.collection_id IS NULL OR B.collection_id=0) AND
      (B.ID is NULL or B.id NOT IN (SELECT collection_id FROM collections));
```

Although I didn't change them, `p` would be a better alias for `products` and `pm` a better alias for `productmeta`.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon! That was a little lame, I did the NULL check on the previous clauses. My Bad!